# Prove (or refute) that $P(x)-{b}^{x}+1$ always has a nonnegative solution for all polynomials $P(x\ge 0)\ge 0$ and all $b>1$.

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

It would make sense that there's always a solution, since I'm pretty sure that equations of the form $a^{x}$ diverge faster than $x^{a}$, but does anyone have a proof?

EDIT: Whoops, sorry, I meant $P(x)-{b}^{x}+1$.

EDIT2: I really fell short on this question. I also meant $b>1$

Comment: Since $P(0)+1\geq b^0$, this is equivalent to the question of whether there exists $x>0$ such that $P(x)+1<b^x$, and in fact the stronger statement holds that there exists $M$ such that $P(x)+1< b^x$ for all $x>M$.  Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/111918/

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $P(x)=x+1$, $b=2$.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I made a dumb mistake. I meant $+1$ instead of $-1$. Basically, I'm trying to show that exponential functions always diverge faster than polynomials.