# Asymptotic growth of function

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, exponentiation

### Question

> I want to arrange which is asymptotically faster -:
>
> $$n^{100},2^{n},n^{\log\,n}$$

### My approach

I know that Exponential function will beat Polynomial function from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111918/growth-of-exponential-functions-vs-polynomial)

but i am thinking of different way of solving it.

> let $$f_{1}=n^{100},f_{2}=2^{n},f_{3}=n^{\log n}$$

Take log both sides-:

$$y_{1}=\log f_{1}=100 *\log\,n$$
$$y_{2}=\log f_{2}=n$$

$$y_{3}=\log \,f_{3}=\log\,(\log\,n*n)$$

> hence $$f_{2}>f_{3}>f_{1}$$

Am i right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It works because of the continuity of $\log$ and $\exp$. $$\log f\leq\log g\iff \log\frac fg\leq 0\iff f\leq g$$

Comment: It seems more straight forward to rewrite your functions using $x = e^{\ln x}$. Then you're just comparing $\{e^{100\ln n}, e^{(\ln 2) n}, e^{(\ln n)^2}\}$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas No, it's not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take logarithms of the three quantities, it is then clear that (for sufficinetly large $n$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
100 \ln n < (\ln n)^2 < n \ln 2.
\end{eqnarray*}
So your answer should be $ f_1 < f_3 < f_2 $.

Comment: That answer has $f_1> f_3,$

Comment: @zhw. You are right ...

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit can you please explain that after taking log of $f_{3}$, it is $(\ln n )^{2}$.I am okk upto $\log \log n \, n$

Comment: $ \ln (n^m) = m \ln n $ ... now let $m = \ln n$ ... so its $ \ln n \times \ln n$.