# Why is $\mathrm{gcd}(n^a+b,(n+1)^a+b)$ almost always prime when $n$ is large?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, coprime, big-numbers

Given is this function:

$$
m=\mathrm{gcd}(n^a+b,(n+1)^a+b)\\
a,b,c\in\mathbb{N} 
$$

On [OEIS A118119](https://oeis.org/A118119), for $2\leq a\leq 84$ and $b=1$, the smallest values for $n$ in each case where this expression is greater than 1 are given. Comparable lists for $b=2$ to $b=19$ are [OEIS A255852](https://oeis.org/A255852) to [OEIS A255869](https://oeis.org/A255869). Among them you can find quite large values for n. For example [OEIS A255852](https://oeis.org/A255852) says (not in the actual list, but in the comment) that the smallest $n$ in the case of $a=47,b=2$ is a number with 320 decimal places.

I am most interested in values of $m$ that are composite numbers, because that would help me a lot in solving [another problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4610851/36642). (See also my comment at the end of my question.)

The values for $m$ are not shown in the tables linked above, but you can easily work them out for yourself. For example, I get these values:

$$
a=8, b=18, n=5 \rightarrow m=187 = 11\cdot 17\\
\mathrm{gcd}(5^{8}+18,(5+1)^{8}+18)=187\\
\,\\
a=9, b=8, n=5 \rightarrow m=11557 = 7\cdot 13\cdot 127\\
\mathrm{gcd}(5^{9}+8,(5+1)^{9}+8)=11557\\
\,\\
a=50, b=1, n=2 \rightarrow m=12625 = 5^3\cdot 101\\
\mathrm{gcd}(2^{50}+1,(2+1)^{50}+1)=12625\\
\,\\
a=72, b=1, n=2 \rightarrow m=55969=97\cdot 577\\
\mathrm{gcd}(2^{72}+1,(2+1)^{72}+1)=55969
$$

But as soon as $n$ becomes bigger, all values listed in the 20 tables mentioned above, result in values for $m$ that are prime. Here is an examples:

$$
a=9, b=16, n=5982 \rightarrow m=31177\,\,\mathrm{is\,prime}\\
\mathrm{gcd}(5982^{9}+16,(5982+1)^{9}+16)=31177
$$

I am interested in those combinations of $a$ and $b$, where $n$ has more than about 20 decimal digits. But in all of the cases listed in the tables, I always get prime numbers for $m$:

$$
a=23, b=13, n=320594291825643656342 \rightarrow m=735616280024182244143\,\,\mathrm{is\,prime}\\
\,\\
a=17, b=9, n=8424432925592889329288197322308900672459420460792433 \rightarrow m=8936582237915716659950962253358945635793453256935559\,\,\mathrm{is\,prime}\\
\,\\
a=19, b=6, n=1578270389554680057141787800241971645032008710129107338825798 \rightarrow m=5299875888670549565548724808121659894902032916925752559262837\,\,\mathrm{is\,prime}
$$

## My Questions:

1. Why is it the case, that composite numbers for $m$ appear only for small values of $n$?
2. Is there a combination of $a$ and $b$ not listed in the tables mentioned above, such that $n$ has more than 20 digits and $m$ is a composite number?

---

#### Comment, not part of the question:

Why am I searching for composite numbers for $m$ when $n$ is large?

This has to do with [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4610851/36642) I asked a few days ago.

Let's assume that the smallest $n$ for $a=40, b=12$ where $m=\mathrm{gcd}(n^a+b,(n+1)^a+b)$ is greater than 1 has the value $N>10^{20}$ and the value of $m$ in this case is $M$ where $M=2\cdot M'$. Then I could write these two Python programs:

```
# tests only odd values for n
import math
n = 1
gcd = 1
while gcd == 1:
    n += 2
    gcd = math.gcd(n ** 40 + 12, (n + 1) ** 40 + 12)
```

and

```
# tests only even values for n
import math
n = 2
gcd = 1
while gcd == 1:
    n += 2
    gcd = math.gcd(n ** 40 + 12, (n + 1) ** 40 + 12)
```

Then only one of these programs would halt when it reaches $n=N$ while the other would run forever.

Comment: In your closing comment, it seems likely that both of those programs halt: Given (a,b), there's typically an infinite sequence of "critical n-values", i.e. n such that gcd(f(n),f(n+1))>1, and *typically they don't all have the same parity*; consequently, whichever program halts when it hits the smallest critical n-value (N), the other program will halt when it hits the smallest critical n-value of opposite parity.