# The phenomenon of exceptions for small values

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I am teaching a Linear Algebra class for first year students and one problem we are discussing in class is the fact that the sum of all elements in a finite field $F$ is $0$ if $|F|>2$. This result is not true in $\mathbb F_2$, a colloquial explanation would be that there is not enough "space" in $\mathbb F_2$.

What are some other nice and interesting examples of theorems that are true except for "small" values or boundary cases? (basic or advanced, from any area of maths, ...)

Comment: Cf. [law of small numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_law_of_small_numbers)

Comment: Try proving $1\not= 0$ in a (unitial) ring, except for one small example.  Then explain why that case is not considered a field

Comment: Some examples are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_object), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403359/theorems-with-finite-sets-of-exceptions) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186103/theorems-with-an-extraordinary-exception-or-a-small-number-of-sporadic-exception).