# Very high unique counterexamples in mathematics

Tags: soft-question, examples-counterexamples

There are conjectures that have very high counterexamples, but a plethora of them. What are some not-overly-specific conjectures about a natural number $n$ that have only one high counterexample. (I want only two different things to happen, either it is, or it isn't. I don't want anything like Every number has at most 10 "somethings" because examples can be characterized by the conjecture itself.)  The best one I know of is the "conjecture" that the symmetric group on n objects doesn't have any outer automorphism, which fails for only $n = 6$.

**Edit:** Here's one for $n = 3107$: The $n^{th}$ square number isn't a stella octangula number unless $n = 1$.

Comment: "Every natural number is different from $18690421!$".

Comment: That should be counted as overly specific.

Comment: Given the lack of specificity on what "not-overly-specific" means...

Comment: What I want in an extremely large counterexample that is the *only* counterexample.

Comment: Why? $\!\!\! \! $

Comment: Take an induction proof that only fails because the base case fails then change the statement so that the base case appears after the high number limit.

Comment: Similar question (without requirement on magnitude I guess) has been asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074126 and closed as duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186103, both following same pattern of first comments as here :)

Comment: Thanks. I might post an answer there.