"Almost true": non-trivial claims that have exactly one counterexample
Question:

What are some non-trivial claims that have exactly one counterexample?


Example 1:
"There is no Pythagorean triple whose numbers are consecutive terms in a row of Pascal's triangle." There is exactly one counterexample: $\left\{\binom{62}{26},\binom{62}{27},\binom{62}{28}\right\}$. proof
Example 2:
"If $n^2>1$ cannonballs are laid on the ground in a filled square formation, then they cannot all be used to make a square pyramid of cannonballs." There is exactly one counterexample: $n=70$. (from this answer)
Example 3:
"No number is equal to the sum of the subfactorials of its digits." There is exactly one counterexample: $148349$. (from this answer)

Remarks:

It must be proven that there exists exactly one counterexample.
Let's exclude trivially false claims, i.e. claims that are obviously false, even if one has never heard the claim before, such as "There is no even prime number" (an obvious counterexample is $2$), or "For integers $n>1$, the equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ has no integer solutions" (an obvious counterexample is $n=2$; it is not obvious that this is the only counterexample, but the claim is still obviously false). (Note: I added the second example after a lot of answers were already given, to clarify this restriction.)
Let's exclude ad hoc claims, i.e. claims that are purposely designed to have exactly one counterexample, such as "There is no integer $n$ such that $n=\frac{600}{\pi^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}$" (the counterexample is n=100). That is, the claims should be reasonably natural claims.


This question was inspired by the question "Conjectures that have been disproved with extremely large counterexamples?".

Exotic spheres (in dimension $4$) come to my mind. But I am not experienced enough with that topic to write a good answer.

Related (but different) question about counterexamples which appear for low numbers.

Very similar question - the difference is here you only want one counterexample, but over there the list of counterexamples was just required to be "small". But many examples posted there fit here as well.

@MartinBrandenburg I'm not sure if the "Very similar question" is that similar. For example, this answer says that the only consecutive positive integer powers are 8,9. If we express this as the claim "The only consecutive positive integer powers are 8,9", then there is no counterexample, so it doesn't fit my question. On the other hand, if we express it as the claim "There are no consecutive positive integer powers", then it has an obvious counterexample, so it is a rather trivial claim, so it doesn't really fit my question.

@MartinBrandenburg Isn't the existence/non-existence of exotic spheres in dimension $4$ open?

@MartinBrandenburg: On the Wikipedia article, it states that it is unkown whether exotic $4$-spheres exist. On the other hand, it is known that (i) exotic $7$-spheres exist, and (ii) exotic $\mathbb R^4$s exist (i.e. smooth manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$ with its standard smooth structure).

"All prime numbers are odd" is too trivial?

@user "Odd" is just a synonym of "not divisible by 2", and for any prime p, "all prime numbers are not divisible by p" is a fairly trivial example of a statement with exactly one counterexample.

@Idran Yes I agree with you! Thanks

I tried to edit Example 2 to reflect that 70 is not a square number, but adding two characters was not enough.

@AntonSherwood Thanks, I have fixed it.

This question is similar to: What are some interesting sole exceptions or counterexamples?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TravisWillse My question excludes claims that are obviously false, for example "All prime numbers are odd". (Whether answers to my question adhere to this exclusion is another matter.) The question in your link allows such claims (rephrased as a theorem with a sole counterexample). Since my question already mentions this exclusion, I'm not sure how I should edit it.

Cannonball problem
No distinct positive integers $(M, N)$ satisfy
$$ \frac16N(N+1)(2N+1) = M^2,$$
except for $(M,N)=(70,24)$. One might argue that this is the reason why Leech lattice exists and has such outstanding properties.

There are a quite a few variations on this using different polygonal bases (e.g. hexagon with same number of balls as hexagonal pyramid)  - Some bases have no solutions, some one or two, and some may have infinitely many.

(1, 1) is also a solution. I'd suggest adding a "non-trivial" qualification to your answer. Also, it obviously feels like there's a link with the Leech lattice. Do you happen to know if anyone has shown how that might work?

@FrancisDavey Regarding $(1,1)$, the answer says "distinct".

@Dan - I missed that.

When reading the question, the Leech lattice right came to my mind, but I wondered how to make it appear as the unique counterexample of something. Well done!

@FrancisDavey: the Wikipedia article (linked in the answer) mentions the Leech lattice with a reference to a post by John Baez https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week95.html , which explains how this works.
As for excluding (1, 1), yes, I cheated a tiny bit. Indeed, "non-trivial" rather than "distinct" would be somewhat more honest, but also a bit ambiguous.

By identifying the problem with arrangements of cannonballs (or oranges, baseballs, etc) we elevate this example over the "trivial" (1,1) case. Few people would identify just one ball as specifically a square pyramidal arrangement.

@OscarLanzi - ah, that's a really nice reframing.

$\mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique differential structure except for $n=4$ where there are an uncountably infinite number (Wikipedia). I like this because the exception is very wrong.

4-dimensional space, what's wrong with you?
PS: +1

@MartinBrandenburg: The failure of the Whitney trick, mostly. :)

@anomaly - indeed. As other answers have mentioned, small dimensions can be like that. I remember a lecture by Michael Atiyah which he started by saying that in two dimensions you can't really do anything interesting because there aren't enough dimensions. As dimensions increase, you can do more complicated things (like knots) but once you get to five or more, you have so many dimensions you can simplify things again. Four dimensions is the sweet spot.

"very wrong", love it! :)

I am fond of the fact that the automorphisms of $S_n$ are always inner automorphisms, with the sole exception of $n=6$.

For $n \geq 0$, the commutator subgroup of the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ is always the special linear group $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$, with the exception of $n=2$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_2$. Proof.

There are no positive integers $a \neq b$ such that $a^b = b^a$, with the exception of $2^4=4^2$.

Catalan's conjecture

The only solution in the natural numbers for $x^a-y^b=1$ is $x=b=3,\; y=a=2$.

which can be stated in this form to possibly fit as an answer:

There are no consecutive powers of natural numbers, except 8 and 9.


Are the words "except $8$ or $9$" part of the claim? If yes, then the claim has no counterexample. If no, then the claim is trivial (because there is an obvious counterexample).

@Dan in fact, the counterexample is not so obvious at all. It took some 200 years to finally prove that this is the only counterexample. And if this does not fit as an answer, I don't know what does

I agree that it's not obvious that it is the only counterexample; I meant that it is obvious that a counterexample exists.

@Dan For what it's worth, given the text of the question, it's not obvious to me that "there are no consecutive pairs of perfect powers" would be considered a "trivial claim" on account of its rather obvious counterexample.

@SophieSwett I think what makes a claim like no even primes "trivial" is the fact that it follows directly from the definition of "even" and "prime," rather than the fact that the counterexample is easy to find.

If you dismiss "There are no consecutive powers of natural numbers, except 8 and 9." as "trivial" because the numbers in the counterexample are below 10 and thus easy to find, then ALMOST ALL answers on this page must also be dismissed. I'd recommend either defining "trivial" a whole lot better (eg, make "trivial" mean that both the counterexample and the proof that it's the only one be trivial), or just removing the requirement and merely downvoting uninteresting/truistic submissions like "no positive int multiplied by itself, makes itself, except 1"

@DewiMorgan I have edited to the question to clarify the restrictions.

@Dan That is a weird restriction that you have added to this question. And it comes quite late. It makes a lot of the answers suddenly offtopic. The interesting part in almost all the examples is that the counterexample is the only one. I suggest that you revert your edit and ask a separate question if that is what you are really looking for.

@MartinBrandenburg From the beginning, I excluded trivial claims. By that, I meant claims that are obviously false. But I think some people thought I meant "claims for which it is obvious that there is exactly one counterexample". But that's not what I meant, so I clarified the OP by adding the thing about $x^n+y^n=z^n$. (I think my exclusion is necessary to focus the question; with the mistaken interpretation of my exclusion, there are just too many possible answers.)

Almost true: no number is equal to the sum of the subfactorials of its digits.
The only counterexample is $148349=!1+!4+!8+!3+!4+!9$.
The subfactorial $!n$ is the number of derangements of a set of $n$ elements, that is, the number of permutations $\rho$ of the set with no $x$ such that $\rho(x)=x$. Values are tabulated, with scads of information, at https://oeis.org/A000166. The result is attributed to Madachy, J. S., Madachy's Mathematical Recreations. New York: Dover, p. 167, 1979.

Is this true only in base 10?

@Neil, all I know is what I wrote. I don't know whether anyone has looked into this.

In base $5$ there is a much smaller counterexample: $14_5=!1+!4$.

Zsigmondy's theorem states that if $a > b > 0$ are coprime integers, then for any integer $n > 2$, there is a prime number $p$ dividing $a^n - b^n$ and not dividing $a^k - b^k$ for all positive integers $k < n$, with the sole exception of $a=2, b=1, n=6$.

Off the top of my head, one distinct problem (distinct from the answers already given) comes to mind. Read it on this site only a while back.
Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with non-negative entries. Let $\gamma(A)$ denote the smallest positive integer $r$ (if it exists) such that $A^r$ has only positive entries.
It was conjectured that for every $n$ and every $r<1+(n^2-2n+2)/2$, there is an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $\gamma(A)=r$.
Zhang(1987) proved that $n=11$ is the only exception to this conjecture.

Some details are added in my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450090/if-p-is-a-regular-transition-probability-matrix-then-pn2-has-no-zero-ele

Background: For any associative algebra $A$, we can define a Jordan algebra $A^+$, which has the same elements as $A$ but the Jordan product $x \ast y = \frac{1}{2}(xy + yx)$.
A Jordan algebra is called special if it arises as a Jordan subalgebra of $A^+$ for some $A$. It is called formally real if a sum of squares vanishes only trivially, i.e. if $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2 = 0$ implies $x_1 = ... = x_k = 0$.
False proposition: A finite-dimensional simple formally real Jordan algebra is special.
Unique counterexample: Let $\mathbb{A} = H_3(\mathbb{O}$) be the $3\times3$ Hermitian matrices with octonion entries, and the usual formula from above for the Jordan product. Since the Octonions are non-associative, this is not  special in the obvious way, despite coming from a matrix algebra. It turns out that it is not special at all.
The uniqueness of this property is why $\mathbb{A}$ is sometimes called the exceptional Jordan algebra. It's also known as the Albert algebra.

A simple Lie group is a connected non-abelian Lie group $G$ which does not have nontrivial connected normal subgroups. Let us consider the special orthogonal groups, that is, the groups of the form$$SO(n,\Bbb R)=\left\{M\in GL(n,\Bbb R)\,\middle|\,M.M^T=\operatorname{Id}_n\wedge\det M=1\right\},$$with $n\in\Bbb N$. Well, $SO(1,\Bbb R)$ and $SO(2,\Bbb R)$ are abelian, and therefore they cannot be simple. What about $SO(n,\Bbb R)$ with $n\geqslant3$? It turns out that they are all simple Lie groups, except when $n=4$.

This is an answer I gave years ago to another question, Accidents of small $n$.
but it works equally well here,
The alternating group $A_n$ is simple for $n\neq4$.

The alternating group is also not simple for $n=0,1,2$ (the trivial group is too simple to be simple).

Almost true: there are no Carmichael numbers of the form $15pq$, $p$ and $q$ being prime numbers.
The only counterexample is $62745$.
Some explanation: a Carmichael number is a positive composite integer $n$ such that $a^{n-1}\equiv1\bmod n$ for every integer $a$ prime to $n$.
I found this statement-with-unique-counterexample in Roberts, Lure of the Integers, the section on $561$ (page 242). Roberts refers to H. J. A. Duparc, On Carmichael numbers, Simon Stevin 29 (1952) 21--24. Duparc's paper is available at https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/6931/6931D.pdf

Kind of similar to your example of the triangle whose sides are consecutive in Pascal's triangle: I asked a question about Pythagorean right triangles with repunit areas, and it seems (but is still unproven as far as I know) that the triangle with sides $\{693, 1924, 2045\}$ and area $666666$ is the only one.

"Let be $U$ non-empty simply connected open subset of $\mathbb C$, then there is a biholomorphic mapping from $U$ onto the open unit disk." has only a counterexample: $U = \mathbb C$.

Inspired by this question:
A polyhedron consisting entirely of pentagons must have an even number and at least twelve of them, a result easily verified using the Euler characteristic. But among the counts allowed by these constraints fourteen alone is impossible to reach.
A similar situation turns out to be true of polydedra with quadrangular faces. The Euler characteristic allows any number of faces greater than or equal to six, but no polyhedron exists specifically with seven quadrangular faces.
It turns out that there is a relationship between these two exceptional cases. Many readers know the graphical relationship between a cube and a regular dodecahedron. Less known is that this relationship also holds for other polyhedra: a polyhedron with $n$ quadrangular faces corresponds with one having $2n$ pentagonal faces.
When seven is an unlucky number
Consider the figure below, in which the cells of a square grid are subdivided by the blue lines to form trapezoidal and triangular pieces. A trapezoid plus the triangle sharing a common edge of the square grid form a pentagon.

On the left we extract six cells in the form of an unfolded cube. When these are wrapped up to reconstitute the cube, the dividing lines within the squares form a graph correspinding to the regular dodecahedron, which can be adjusted by moving the blue vertices outwards to become conspherical with the cube vertices.
On the right there are nine divided square cells, which can be wrapped up by tucking the left square into the right corner, folding the top and bottom triplets together, and deforming the squares into rhombi or kites to fit the occluded edges toether. This gives the Herschel enneahedron (J??ErYsw?w? in graph6 encoding), a polyhedron having $D_{3h}$ symmetry; the blue lines then graphically define one of two mirror-image pentagonal 18-hedra with $D_3$ symmetry (the symmetry is reduced because the division of the squares is not fully symmetric). Like the cube and regular dodecahedron, the enneahedron and mirror-image pair of 18-hedra are graphichally unique for the number and polygonal type of faces.
We then find that there is no way to wrap a set of exactly seven contiguous squares into a polyhedron, even allowing for deformation of the faces to fit edges together. So the non-existences of a quadrangular heptahedron and a pentagonal tetrakaidecahedron fall together.

Theorem 15 of Rosser and Schoenfeld's renowed paper "Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers", Illinois J. Math. 6 (1962) 64-94 (open access here) states that, for an integer $n \geq 3$, the following inequality holds
$$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} < e^{\gamma}\log\log n + \frac{5}{2\log\log n},$$
except when $n = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 = 223092870$, ie. when $n$ is the product of the nine first prime numbers. Here $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function and $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.
NB: one requires $n\geq 3$ since $n\leq 1$ does not make sense, and $n=2$ is trivially wrong as $\log\log 2 < 0$.

It's also interesting to note that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to $$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} < e^{\gamma}\log\log n + \frac{3.644415}{\sqrt{\log n}}$$ for all $n>P$, where $P$ is the product of the first $120569$ primes.

Let be $\gamma$ a closed curve surrounding 0:
$$\int_\gamma z^n\,dz = 0$$
for all $n\in\mathbb Z,\ n\ne -1$.

Given any additive sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ of real numbers with first term $1,[a_0 = 1, a_1 = b, \, \text{and for all} \,\, n > 1, a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}]$,
there exists no real number $b$ as second term, such that the limit of
the ratio $a_n / a_{n-1}$ as $n \to \infty$, fails to approach
golden number $\phi = \dfrac{(1 + \sqrt 5)}{2}$.
The single counterexample is $b = -\dfrac{1}{\phi} = \dfrac{(1 - \sqrt 5)}{2}$.
SOURCE: Michael W. Ecker, Generalized Additive Sequences from Fibonacci Numbers, Mathematics and Computer Education, Winter 2011-2012, Vol. 46, No. 1, p. 41-52.

Unfortunately, the publication MACE folded four years later after decades of existence. Anybody who wishes the doc file or pdf that I can create should write me at
DrMWEcker at aol.com

Suppose a linear, homogeneous second-order difference equation with constant coefficients has indicial roots $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$, with $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|$. Then we get the subdominant behavior when $a_1=1,a_2=\lambda_2$. E.g. compare $(1,-1,1,-1,...)$ with other solutions of $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_n$.

The line graph $L(G)$ of a graph $G$ is defined as $V(L(G)) = E(G)$, two vertices of $L(G)$ are adjacent if and only if their corresponding edges share a common vertex.
The structure of a connected graph $G$ can be recovered completely from its line graph with one exception. Meaning if $G \not\simeq H$ then $L(G) \not\simeq L(H)$, except for $L(K_3) \simeq L(K_{1,3})$.

$$
3^3 + 4^4 + 3^3 + 5^5 = 3435
$$
is the only positive integer with this property other than trivial $1^1 = 1$.

You are really nice for mentioning this great type Munchausen numbers, I suggest reading the following pdf for proof that 3435 is the only non-trivial Munchausen number, and the proof is elementary: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D9E2-UvpSqLeGXNpAN5WZpZhUYn-GE_M/view?usp=sharing

There is no vector space $R^n$ with $n\ne 3$ where it is possible to define a not trivial cross product, with the only exception of $n=7$, where we have a family of 480 different cross products.

I feel like this is more a non-trivial claim that has exactly two counterexamples, the claim is just phrased to exclude one of them. :P

Kinda agree with @Idran, this offered as an answer feels very superficial...

This answer is more appropriate over at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178183/accidents-of-small-n

Let $\ell^{p}$ be the space of complex sequences that are $p-$summable, where $p \in [1,\infty)$. Then non of them is a Hilbert space.
There is unique counterexample which is when $p=2$.
see:$\ell_p$ is Hilbert if and only if $p=2$

Your second and third examples are given in the question as examples of trivial claims, and Catalan's conjecture was already posted in a previous answer.

@Idran Then I will delete them, thanks for your advice.

A tournament is a complete graph with $n$ players in which each edge has been given an orientation. (The name comes from the idea that a tournament encodes the results of a round-robin contest, with an edge from $u$ to $v$ indicating that $u$ won her game against $v$.)
A champion in a tournament $T$ (sometimes called a king) is a node $c$ of $T$ where there is a directed path of length at most 2 from $c$ to each player in $T$. A classic theorem on tournaments states that every nonempty tournament has at least one champion.
The question then arises: given $n \ge 1$ and $1 \le k \le n$, is there an $n$-player tournament with exactly $k$ champions? The answer is yes, except if $k = 2$ or $n = k = 4$.
(This technically has more that one counterexample, but the $(4, 4)$ case definitely stands out!)

$$\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$
Alternate formulation with less obvious exception:
$$(n+1)\int x^ndx=x^{n+1}+C^{\prime}$$

The exception being $n=-1$?

@Suzet - Yes. And it's not really trivial.

I guess that it's all about constructing the exponential function? Once it's defined, in a way or another, and you know that it satisfies the equation $f' = f$, then it follows that its inverse function is an antiderivative of $1/x$.

The equality$$\int x^n,\mathrm dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$makes no sense if $n=-1$ and it is very easy to check in all other case. So, you do you claim that “it's not really trivial”?

@JoséCarlosSantos - The claim is non trivial, but the exception is easy to prove.

To fix these issues, I suggest to write your equation as $$(n+1) \int x^n , \mathrm{d}x = x^{n+1}.$$

Let $p(z) \ = \ z^n + p_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \ldots + p_1z + p_0$ be a complex polynomial. Then its polar derivative $q$ with respect to the pole $\alpha \ \in \ \mathbb{C}$ is defined by
$$
q(z) \ = \ p(z) - \frac{1}{n}(z-\alpha)p´(z) \, ,
$$
where $p´(z)$ is its usual derivative. The claim that $q(z)$ is of degree $n-1$ has only one counterexample $\alpha \, = \, c$, where $c$ is the centroid of the zeros of $p$.
This is a direct consequence of the difference of the sum of the zeros and critical points (zeros of the derivative) always being equal to $c$ and the only reason that certain matrices I am particularly interested in exist at all.
In the case $\alpha \, = \, c$, the degree of $q$ is at most $n-2$, but if the coefficients of $p$ fulfill certain conditions, it will be lower still. The extreme case is $p(z) \, = \, (z-k)^n$, where $k$ is a fixed complex number. Then $k \, = \, c$ and $q$ with respect to $c$ vanishes.

Shall the reason be that $p_{n-1} = nc$? I was wondering what centroid means, I understand that it is the mean value of the zeros of $p$?

@Suzet: $p_{n-1} = -nc$, except for that, you are correct. I have heard the expressions arithmetic mean value or barycenter for $c$, too.

Thanks for the explanation! My bad for the sign.

Claim: There is no Pythagorean triple whose numbers are consecutive.
The one (well-known) counterexample is $3^2+4^2=5^2$.
Proof (easy but arguably not trivial):
If$$a^2+(a+1)^2=(a+2)^2$$then$$2a^2+2a+1=a^2+4a+4$$$$a^2=2a+3$$and$$a=3$$

This is trivial by any standard. It's a quadratic equation.
