# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\sin{(\pi x)}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\,dx =\frac{\pi e}{24} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I've found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/505439/153012) the following integral.

$$I = \int_{0}^{1}\sin{(\pi (1-x))}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sin{(\pi x)}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\,dx=\frac{\pi e}{24}$$

I've never seen it before and I also didn't find the evaluation on math.se. How could we verify it?

If it is a well-known integral, then could you give a reference?

Comment: I just want to say good luck to whoever tries to figure this one out.

Comment: Damn, this is a good one.

Comment: I think I can show the first part.  I'll take a crack at the second.

Comment: Aren't the two integrals trivially identical? Since $\sin(\pi-z) = \sin(z)$?

Comment: @BennettGardiner  Heh. Good call.  It also seems to follow from the substitution $u=1-x$.

Comment: The problem is the second equality. The first one is just because of aesthetics.

Comment: @Eric Lawson please leave your alternate form as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: *I'm looking for an answer using real calculus methods* - You won't get it. After all, there's a reason why God created complex analysis, and integrals like this or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant) are among them...

Comment: @Lucian Then a complete solution using complex analysis also would be nice.

Comment: @Lucian So true :'(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two curious "identities" on $x^x$,$e$,and $\pi$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242587/two-curious-identities-on-xx-e-and-pi)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Torsten Carleman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsten_Carleman) $[2]$ proved in 1922 that

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(a_1a_2\cdots a_n\right)^{1/n} < e\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n,
> $$

where $a_n \geq 0$, $n=1,2,\dots$, and $0 < \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$. Thenceforth, this result is known as [Carleman's inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarlemansInequality.html). There exists a number of refined versions of Carleman's original work $[3, 6]$. It has turned out that the following generalization is – from our point of view – important, which is proved by Yang $[7]$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(a_1a_2\cdots a_n\right)^{1/n} < e\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{b_k}{(n+1)^k}\right)a_n,
$$

with $b_1 = 1/2, b_2 = 1/24, b_3 = 1/48, b_4 = 73/5670, b_5 = 11/1280, b_6 = 1945/580608$.
On the last page of his paper, Yang $[7]$ conjectured that if
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{(x+1)^n}\right), \quad x>0,
$$

then $b_n > 0$, $n=1,2,\dots.$ In fact, the constants $b_4$ and $b_6$ are not corrent in Yang's work, the correct values are $b_4 = 73/5760$ and $b_6 = 3625/580608$. Later, this conjecture was proved and discussed by Yang $[8]$, Gylletberg and Ping $[4]$, and Yue $[9]$. They are using the recurrence
$$
b_1 = \frac12, \quad b_n = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{b_{n-k-1}}{k+2} \right), \quad n = 2,3,\dots.
$$
The recurrence is given in a somewhat more compact form in Finch's manuscript $[3]$, as the following:

> $$
> b_0 = -1, \quad b_n = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_{n-k}}{k+1}, \quad n = 1,2,\dots.
> $$

The first ten values of the sequence are listed in the next table.
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
b_0 & -1 \\ \hline b_1 & 1/2 \\ \hline b_2 & 1/24 \\ \hline b_3 & 1/48 \\ \hline b_4 & 73/5760 \\ \hline b_5 & 11/1280 \\ \hline b_6 & 3625/580608 \\ \hline b_7 & 5525/1161216 \\ \hline b_8 & 5233001/1393459200 \\ \hline b_9 & 1212281/398131200 \\ \hline b_{10} & 927777937/367873228800 \\
\hline
\end{array}
The numerators are recorded as [A249276](http://oeis.org/A249276), and the denominators as [A249277](http://oeis.org/A249277) in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/). I've calculated the $b_n$ sequence in the range $n=0,\dots,32$, the elements are listed [here](http://mathb.in/145272?key=677ade0f6738b4bc973f3955937b952544a82225).

The following theorem is proved in general in the paper by Hu and Mortici $[5]$, and for the special cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ in the paper by Alzer and Berg $[1]$.

For all integer $n \geq 0$, we have

> $$
> \int_0^1 x^n\sin\left(\pi x\right)x^x\left(1-x\right)^{1-x}\,dx = b_{n+2}\pi e.
> $$

The special case $n=0$ answers my question.

---

**References**

1. H. Alzer, C. Berg, [*Some classes of completely monotonic functions*](http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol27/alzer.html), Annales Academiæ Scientiarum Fennicæ Mathematica, 27, 2002, 445–460. ([pdf](http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol27/alzer.pdf))
2. T. Carleman, [*Sur les fonctions quasi-analytiques*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247679096_Sur_les_functions_quasi-analytiques), Comptes rendus du Ve Congres des Mathematiciens Scandinaves, Helsinki (Helsingfors), 1922, 181–196.
3. S. Finch, [*Carleman's Inequality*](https://oeis.org/A219245/a219245.pdf), manuscript, 2013.
4. M. Gyllenberg, Y. Ping, [*On a conjecture by Yang*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X01977029), Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 264(2), 2001, 687–690.
5. Y. Hu, C. Mortici, [*On the coefficients of an expansion of $(1+1/x)^x$ related to Carleman's inequality*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2236), manuscript, arXiv:1401.2236, 2014.
6. M. Johansson, L.-E. Persson, A. Wedestig, [*Carleman's inequality - History, proofs and some new generalizations*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237246073_Carleman%27s_inequality-history_proofs_and_some_new_generalizations), Journal of Inequalities in Pure and Applied Mathematics, 4(3), 2003.
7. X. Yang, [*On Carleman’s inequality*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X00971555), Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 253(2), 2001, 691–694.
8. X. Yang, [*Approximations for constant $e$ and Their Applications*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X01975924), Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 262(2), 2001, 651–659.
9. H. Yue, [*A Strengthened Carleman’s Inequality*](http://math-res-pub.org/cma/1/2/strengthened-carleman%E2%80%99s-inequality), Communications in Mathematical Analysis, 1(2), 2006, 115–119. ([pdf](https://www.ripublication.com/cma_files/cmav1n2_6.pdf))

---

**Related**

This answer is related to the following stackexchange questions:

- [On the search for an explicit form of a particular integral](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215816/on-the-search-for-an-explicit-form-of-a-particular-integral)
- [Two curious “identities” on $x^x, e$, and $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242587/two-curious-identities-on-xx-e-and-pi)
- [Evaluating an integral using real methods](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226870/evaluating-an-integral-using-real-methods)

Comment: There might be a similar generalization to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593476/calculate-int-01-fracx-1-x-left1-x-rightx-2-mathrmb?noredirect=1&lq=1, but I am not sure.

Comment: @user153012 Very nice information, thanks. (+1)

Answer (score 45):

This one can be done with "residue at infinity" calculation. This method is shown in the Example VI of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration .

First, we use $z^z = \exp ( z \log z )$ where $\log z$ is defined for $-\pi\leq \arg z < \pi$.

For $(1-z)^{1-z} = \exp ( (1-z)\log (1-z) )$, we use $\log (1-z)$ defined for $0\leq \arg(1-z) <2\pi$.

Then, let  $f(z)= \exp( i\pi z + z \log z + (1-z) \log (1-z) )$.

As shown in the Ex VI in the wikipedia link, we can prove that $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(1,\infty)$, so that the cut of $f(z)$ is $[0,1]$.

We use the contour: (consisted of upper segment: slightly above $[0,1]$, lower segment: slightly below $[0,1]$, circle of small radius enclosing $0$, and circle of small radius enclosing $1$, that looks like a dumbbell having knobs at $0$ and $1$, can someone edit this and include a picture of it please? In fact, this is also the same contour as in Ex VI, with different endpoints.)

On the upper segment, the function $f$ gives, for $0\leq r \leq 1$, 
$$\exp(i\pi r) r^r (1-r)^{1-r} \exp( (1-r) 2\pi i ).$$

On the lower segment, the function $f$ gives, for $0\leq r \leq 1$, 
$$\exp(i\pi r) r^r(1-r)^{1-r}. $$

Since the functions are bounded, the integrals over circles vanishes when the radius tend to zero.

Thus, the integral of $f(z)$ over the contour, is the integral over the upper and lower segments, which contribute to

$$\int_0^1 \exp(i\pi r) r^r (1-r)^{1-r} dr - \int_0^1 \exp(-i\pi r) r^r(1-r)^{1-r} dr$$

which is 
$$
2i \int_0^1 \sin(\pi r) r^r (1-r)^{1-r} dr.$$

By the Cauchy residue theorem, the integral over the contour is
$$
-2\pi i \textrm{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) = 2\pi i \textrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} f(\frac 1 z).$$

From a long and tedious calculation of residue, it turns out that the value on the right is 
$$
2i \frac{\pi e}{24}.$$
Then we have the result:
$$ 
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi r) r^r (1-r)^{1-r} dr = \frac{\pi e}{24}.$$

Comment: Could we get closed forms of the integral with other integrand limits by similar long and tedious calculation? For example between $1$ and $3/2$ or between $3/2$ and $2$, or between $2$ and $5/2$, or any other not that nice arbitrary $a$ and $b$?

Comment: It is of interest to note that \begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} e^{i \pi x} \, x^{x} (1-x)^{1-x} \, dx = i \, \frac{\pi e}{4!} \end{align}

Comment: @user153012 I do not know for sure, but the calculation would be much more difficult for other limits.

Comment: @Leucippus That one is easy to see when you notice that the integral with $\cos \pi x$ vanishes. My solution came out like this when started computing that one instead.

Comment: (For anyone scratching their heads, this is an old post don't downvote!)

Comment: @Zach466920 Don't worry, nobody downvoted.