# Exact values of error function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, error-function

The [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) is defined as

$$\operatorname{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^z e^{-t^2} \, dt.$$

We know that the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

Because of the symmetry of the integrand it is also true, that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$

From here and from the definition of definite integral we know two exact values of the $\operatorname{erf}$ function, these are $\operatorname{erf}(0)=0$ and $\operatorname{erf}(\infty)=1$.

**Question.** Is there an exact closed-form value of $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ for some $z\neq0,\infty\,$?

Because of $(3)$ and $(4)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), the question is equivalent to the following. Are there a closed-form expression for some $z\neq 0,\infty$ of the following [confluent hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function)?

$${_1F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-z^2\right),$$
$${_1F_1}\left(1;\frac{3}{2};z^2\right).$$

Or because of $(5)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) with [the lower incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), for some $z \neq 0,\infty$

$$ \gamma\left(\frac 12, z^2 \right).$$

---

More general, is there any $(a,b)$ nonzero and finite pair for that we have a closed-form of the following?

$$\int_a^b e^{-x^2} \, dx,$$

where $a<b$.

Comment: for the error function there is no known closed form. Only very good approximations. But if you are talking about some specific points, it doesnt make sense because it will definitely pass through some $\pi$-like known values or some rational numbers.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Yes I know that the error function has not closed-form. I'm talking about a closed-form at some $z$ beside $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: See my answer to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967362).

Comment: so you are saying that if a closed form can be found for some subset of the whole real line.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Yes.

Comment: The third case is $z=-\infty$.

Comment: @user153012: you may be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355307) question as well.

Comment: You can use $\text{erf}(\text{erf}^{-1}(x))=x$ for fun