# How to evaluate $\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^py^q \sin(\pi xy) (xy)^{xy} (1-xy)^{1-xy} \, dx \, dy$ where $p,q$ are integers?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For a positive integer $n$ the terms given by
\begin{align}
-\int_0^1 x^n  \sin(\pi x) x^x (1-x)^{1-x} dx \\
= \int_0^1\int_0^1 (xy)^n \sin(\pi xy) (xy)^{xy} \frac{(1-xy)^{1-xy}}{\ln (xy)}  dx dy \end{align}
are rationals mutiple of $e\pi$. The left side integral, when $n=0$, can be found here: [Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\sin{(\pi x)}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\,dx =\frac{\pi e}{24} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958624/prove-that-int-01-sin-pi-xxx1-x1-x-dx-frac-pi-e24)

I'm interessed in knowing about
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^py^q \sin(\pi xy) (xy)^{xy} \frac{(1-xy)^{1-xy}}{\ln (xy)}  dx dy \end{align}
where $p,q$ are positive integers. Maybe someone can show a way to evaluate a specific case and I will try to conjecture a general exepression.