# Square factors of $a^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find $a$ such that $a^2+1$ is not squarefree, meaning that none of its factors are square numbers. I found that this is the case for $a=7$ but can't think of a way to approach this problem more generally.

Comment: What do you mean by squarefree?

Comment: @gimusi not divisible by the square of an integer

Comment: You want to pick a prime $p$ such that $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$. These are $p=2$ and $p\equiv 1\mod{4}$. Then, for those $p$ solve the congruence $a^2+1\equiv0\mod{p^2}$.

Comment: @gimusi Squarefree means that it has no repeated prime factors.

Comment: Are you trying to find _all_ such $a$, or an easy construction that always generates them?

Comment: Do you mean the prime decomposition of $a^2 + 1$ is not square free?  It looks like you have found such an a in which $a = 7 \to a^2 + 1 = 50 = 2\cdot 5^2$.  You have found such an $a$.  If you're asked to find a counterexample, to show that $a^2 + 1$ is not always square free, you've found it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinitely many $n$ such that $n^2+1$ is squarefree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217910/infinitely-many-n-such-that-n21-is-squarefree)

Comment: Check out Pell's equation to generate lots more examples ... Eg $29^2 \mid 41^2+1$.

Comment: @XcoderX This question is looking for $a^2 + 1$ that is **NOT** square free, and the asker found one such $a$, as asked.

Comment: It is similar...

Comment: @orlp I'm trying to find all such $a$.

Answer (score 2):

For any prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ you have that $a^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has two opposite solutions $\pmod{p}$, and they can be lifted to solutions $\!\!\pmod{p^2}$. For instance, by picking $p=13$ we have that the square roots of $-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ are $5$ and $8$. Let us see if for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ 
$$ (13k+5)^2\equiv -1\pmod{13^2} $$
holds. Of course, since the previous equation is equivalent to
$$ 10k+2 \equiv 0\pmod{13} $$
which is solved by $k\equiv 5\pmod{13}$.
 It follows that $(5\cdot 13+5)^2+1=70^2+1$ is a multiple of $13^2$.

Comment: Thank you. Does this generate all cases? I mean, are there any cases with non-prime square factors?

Comment: @user524960: all the non-squarefree numbers of the form $a^2+1$ can be generated by this procedure, since the odd prime divisors of $a^2+1$ are always of the $4k+1$ form.