Proving the high precision of the series correct to at least half a billion digits
I recently learned about this high-precision series. It is claimed that it is correct to at least half a billion digits. I am curious to know how it works.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left\lfloor n e^{\frac\pi3\sqrt{163}}\right\rfloor}{2^n} = 1280640
$$

It reminds me of Ramanujan's constant,
$$
e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx640320^3+744
$$
which is an almost integer.
Using this approximation and
$$
\left\lfloor n\sqrt[3]{640320^3+744}\right\rfloor\approx 640320n,
$$
It can be shown that the sum is very close to $1280640$.
But my question is, how is it so accurate to at least half a billion digits?
A floor function is involved in it, increasing its accuracy and making it challenging to prove that it is so accurate.

Any proof demonstrating its accuracy is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Some references here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1329516/42969

Did you delete the question you posted to MathOverflow, Pustam? I can't find it. I posted some references in comments there, such as Borwein & Borwein, Strange series and high-precision fraud, The Monthly, August-September 1992, pp 622 to 640.

@GerryMyerson Yes, I deleted it. Thank you for references. My question was being downvoted. Shall I undelete it?

You should work out why it was being downvoted, and edit it so it won't get downvoted, and then undelete it.

Define the real valued function
$$ f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor n x\rfloor}{2^n}. \tag1 $$
Since $ \lfloor x+k\rfloor = k+\lfloor x\rfloor $ for all integer
$k$, this implies
$$ f(k+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor n (k+x)\rfloor}{2^n} =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nk+\lfloor n x\rfloor}{2^n} = 2k+f(x).
\tag2 $$
If $0<x$ and $0<n$ integer, then $0\le\lfloor nx\rfloor\le nx.$
If $0<x<\frac1k$ and $0<n<k$ integer, then $0=\lfloor nx\rfloor$.
This implies
$$ 0 \le f(x)\le\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{\lfloor n x\rfloor}{2^n} \le \sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{n x}{2^n} = 2x\frac{1+k}{2^k}. \tag3 $$
Define the constants
$$ c := e^{\frac\pi3\sqrt{163}}, \,\,
   s := 640320, \,\,
   r := c-s \approx 6\times 10^{-10}<\frac1{10^9}. \tag4 $$
Now use equation $(2)$ to get
$$ f(c) = 2s + f(r) = 1280640 + f(r). \tag5 $$
Use equation $(3)$ to bound $f(r)$ as
$$ 0 < f(r) < 2r\frac{10^9}{2^{10^9}}<\frac2{2^{10^9}}. \tag6 $$
More precisely
$$ \frac1r = 1653264929.0322\dots, \,\, \log_{10}\frac1{f(r)}=497682334.4082\dots \tag7 $$
which is almost half a billion. This answers the question

But my question is, how is it so accurate to at least half a billion digits?

