# What is the example called, where someone was wrongly convinced of a sequence function because of naive induction.

Tags: sequences-and-series, math-history

I remember I have seen a classical example of a mistake, where someone was convinced that a sequence defined somehow had a close form, which did in turn work until some very high $n$. I think the first $n$ to fail was 3 or 5 digits.

Is anyone aware of what is on my mind?

Comment: Even many correct examples do not prove a conjecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a huge list here of [apparently true things that eventually fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/examples-of-apparent-patterns-that-eventually-fail). Maybe you can find what you were looking for here?

Comment: It actually was in there: n=341, fermat primality test