# Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(k^a-\cos{k^ax})\cdot{\mathrm dx\over x^ 2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

RE-EDITED (Because the conjecture of $(1)$ was wrong when I first posted)

Note that $(1)$ is only valid for $n\le4$

Compute the closed form of $(1)$

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(k^a-\cos{k^ax})\cdot{\mathrm dx\over x^2}\tag1$$

---

ORIGINAL POST

Consider the integral $(1)$

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(k^a-\cos{k^ax})\cdot{\mathrm dx\over x^2}=(n!)^a\pi\tag1$$
>   $a\ge1$; Integers

How does one prove $(1)$?

**An attempt:**

Expand the products in $(1)$, then we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(1-\cos x)(2^a-\cos 2^ax)(3^a-\cos 3^ax)\cdots(n^a-\cos n^ax)\over x^2}\mathrm dx\tag2$$

Suggested idea: I guess we could multiply out the brackets and using Contour integration

Or does this product $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(k^a-\cos{k^ax})$ has a closed form?

Recall this recurrence relation

$$\cos (nx)=2\cos[(n-1)x]\cos x-\cos[(n-2)x]\tag3$$

Problem $(1)$ seem tough, I can't see anyway to even changed a bit.

How else do we go about tackling $(1)$?

Comment: It's look like very similar to a result of David Borwein and Jonathan Borwein that I used in another question. The closed form is strongly linked to the form of the sequence $a_{k}$ (in your case $a_{k}=k^{a}$). However this is the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843344/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sinx-sin2x-sin3x-cdots-sinnx-sinn2/1843501#1843501

Comment: (1) seems not to work when $n=5$.

Comment: Yes, it some how failed at $n=5$. Again one of those coincidence mathematics.

Comment: @Bui, pretty strange that it works for $n\leq 4$. What is the source of your question ?

Comment: I have to re-edit my question and ask for a closed form @Zaid Alyafeai.