# $p^2+p+1$ is either prime or semi prime, if $p$ is prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

I am trying to come up with conjectures related to prime numbers and came up with this question. The last question I asked was wrong. So for this question I have tried numbers till $30$. Is this conjecture valid?

Comment: Till $30$ is not very far at all... Write a program.

Comment: As said in the previous comment, you should write a program to know if this conjecture can be true. By the way, if $P=37$, $P^2+P+1=1047=3\times 7 \times 67$ so the conjecture can't be true

Comment: Even if you tried up to $2352342352342135132423523541324236235$ it would prove nothing. I don't have any examples but I would bet there are reasonable conjectures whose first counterexamples are larger than that.

Comment: I would expect (based on nothing concrete) that no polynomial yields only primes or semi primes when evaluated at primes, except for the trivial one $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @lhf $p^2$ is semi-prime, so $f(x) = px$ works too (and allowing $p^2$ is necessary for things as [Chen's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem)

Comment: @user1952009, right, thanks.

Comment: Without electronic help, one can easily jump to false conclusions. Even Fermat falsely conjectured that $2^{2^n}+1$ is prime for all $n\ge 0$. Euler disproved this by showing $641|2^{32}+1$

Comment: @Peter [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Littlewood.27s_theorem) is a famous false conjecture that is valid for up to $10^{23}$

Comment: @MattSamuel The first counterexample to $n^{17}+9$ and $(n+1)^{17}+9$ being not coprime is $n=8424432925592889329288197322308900672459420460792433$

Comment: @wythagoras, where does that come from? Oh, from https://oeis.org/A010034! And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/examples-of-apparent-patterns-that-eventually-fail/111939#111939.

Comment: Skewes' number has to do with another false conjecture about the prime counting function and the integral logarithm.

Answer (score 3):

This is false for $p=37$ because $37^2+37+1=1407= 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 67$.

Comment: Other counterexamples are $61,67,79,107,109,137,139,149,151,163,181,191$, etc.

Comment: you got me just found 107 hehehe

Answer (score 1):

If $p\equiv1$ mod $3$, then $p^2+p+1$ is divisible by $3$, and if $p\equiv2$ or $4$ mod $7$, then $p^2+p+1$ is divisible by $7$, so by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions (and the Chinese Remainder Theorem), there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which $p^2+p+1$ is divisible by both $3$ and $7$, hence neither prime nor semi-prime.