# large numbers as counterexamples

Tags: geometry, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Some mathematical patterns stay true for a set of integers $1..n$ only to break at $n+1$.

What are some nontrivial examples where $n$ is ``large''?

As an example $x^2+x+41$ is prime for $x=1..40$, but not at $41$.

I am particularly looking for examples other than [prime producing polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html). Especially examples suitable for an introductory class.

Comment: $$\binom nr>0$$ for $0\le r\le n$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111461/76284

Comment: In any case, a standard example is Skewes' Number: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewesNumber.html

Answer (score 5):

It's not number theory, but I've always found the Borwein integrals to be fascinating.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral