# Example for a mathematical theorem that has been verified via computer up to very large numbers yet turned out to be false

Tags: proof-writing, computer-assisted-proofs

I am looking for an:

> Example of a mathematical theorem that has been verified via computer up to very large numbers yet turned out to be false

Any suggestions?

Comment: The [Pòlya Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_conjecture)

Comment: @insipidintegrator Was it checked with a computer? Certainly by the time of its disproof in 1958 they had not checked up to $10^9$, or they would have found the first counterexample.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Disproved_conjectures

Comment: See also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/examples-of-patterns-that-eventually-fail

Comment: $li(x)>\pi(x)$ , in fact the sign chances infinite many often.